# I get the error " You can't use `\prevdepth` in horizontal mode" while using `algorithm2e` package

Tags: errors, algorithm2e

I use a separate .tex file for every section in my document.
One of these documents require an algorithm to be written. I use `algorithm2e` package to do so.

Here is my MWE (algorithm is taken from [this website](http://cse.unl.edu/%7Echoueiry/S12-235/files/algo_example.tex)):

```
%!TeX root = Section2

%Section 2
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumerate,tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    
\subsection{Simple algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
\KwIn{A sequence of integers $\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \rangle$}
\KwOut{The index of first location witht he same value as in a previous location in the sequence}
$location \gets 0$\;
$i \gets 2$\;
\While{$i \leq n$ \textbf{and} $location = 0$}{
    $j \gets 1$\;
    \While{$j < i$ \textbf{and} $location = 0$}{
        % The "u" before the "If" makes it so there is no "end" after the statement, so the else will then follow
        \uIf{$a_i = a_j$}{
            $location \gets i$\;
        }
        \Else{
            $j \gets j + 1$\;
        }
    }
    $i \gets i + 1$\;
}
\Return{location}\;
\caption{{\sc FindDuplicate}}
\label{algo:duplicate}
\end{algorithm}

        \subsection{Advanced algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

The output of the algorithm looks like this:
[image]

The indentations and the line numbers are all messed up.
Below are the error messages I get, and I assume the main problem is so called `\prevdepth` command which is used somewhere automatically and causes incompatibility with some other environment.

```
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \advance 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \advance 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! You can't use `\moveright' in math mode.
\algocf@push ...dvance \skiptotal by #1\moveright 
                                                  #1
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Arithmetic overflow.
<recently read> \p@ 
                    
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;

Package relsize Warning: Size requested is too small.
(relsize)                Using 5.0pt instead on input line 70.

! Improper `at' size (0.0pt), replaced by 10pt.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \advance 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \advance 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! You can't use `\moveright' in math mode.
\algocf@push ...dvance \skiptotal by #1\moveright 
                                                  #1
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Arithmetic overflow.
<recently read> \p@ 
                    
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;

Package relsize Warning: Size requested is too small.
(relsize)                Using 5.0pt instead on input line 70.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.70    \Return
             {$max$}\;

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.70    \Return{$max$}\;
                      

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.71    \caption{{\sc Max} finds the maximum number}
                                                  

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.73 \end{algorithm}
                    

Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 73--73
```

Comment: why are you using the standalone class?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is the recommended class while using `\import`. I honestly don't know the difference.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is indeed normal when I switch to `article` class. I have no idea why.

Comment: standalone is very complicated class which tries to crop the page around the content. It is meant to create pictures. Don't use it for arbitrary material.